# How to copy body of appointment including all formatting to email?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

In order to have an automated email sent every week to my team, I have followed [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/635094/scheduled-and-recurring-email-in-outlook) (but I am open to anything else. It is each week a reminder for them to complete something).

It is done using an appointment and a VBA sub that send the content of the appointment as the content of the mail.

But the body of the appointment includes:

- Bullet points
- Hyperlinks to files

This is the format I would like in the email:
[image]

Some formatting is taken, but not the two points mentioned.

Screenshot of what is received:
[image]

How can I get full formatting?

```
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim objMsg As MailItem
    Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    If Item.MessageClass <> "IPM.Appointment" Then 'vérifie s'il s'agit d'un rappel sur RDV
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If (Item.Categories <> "00.CourrielsAutomatiques") Then 'indiquer ici le nom de la catégorie créée pour les mails autos
        Exit Sub
    End If
    objMsg.SendUsingAccount = objMsg.Session.Accounts.Item(1) 'si gestion de plusieurs comptes
    objMsg.To = Item.Location 'ligne Lieu de rendez-vous utilisée pour les adresses
    objMsg.Subject = Item.Subject 'objet du mail
    objMsg.HTMLBody = Item.Body  'corps du mail
    'objMsg.Attachments.Add "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx.jpg" 'pour ajouter une pièce jointe
    objMsg.Send

    Set objMsg = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub copyApptBodyWithFormatting()
  
    Dim olItem As Object
    Dim olItemInspector As Inspector
    Dim olItemWordEditor As Object
    
    Dim olMail As MailItem
    Dim olMailInspector As Inspector
    Dim olMailWordEditor As Object
    
    Set olItem = ActiveInspector.currentItem
    
    If olItem.Class = olAppointment Then
        
        Set olItemInspector = olItem.GetInspector
        Set olItemWordEditor = olItemInspector.WordEditor
        olItemWordEditor.Range.Copy
        
        Set olMail = CreateItem(olMailItem)
          
        With olMail
        
            .Display
            
            Set olMailInspector = .GetInspector
            Set olMailWordEditor = olMailInspector.WordEditor
            
            olMailWordEditor.Range(0, 0).Paste
            
        End With
        
    End If

End Sub
```

---

```vb
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)

    Dim itemInspector As Inspector
    Dim itemWordEditor As Object
    
    Dim objMsg As MailItem
    Dim objMsgInspector As Inspector
    Dim objMsgWordEditor As Object
    
    If Item.MessageClass <> "IPM.Appointment" Then 'vérifie s'il s'agit d'un rappel sur RDV
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If (Item.categories <> "00.CourrielsAutomatiques") Then 'indiquer ici le nom de la catégorie créée pour les mails autos
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set objMsg = CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    objMsg.SendUsingAccount = objMsg.Session.Accounts.Item(1) 'si gestion de plusieurs comptes
    objMsg.To = Item.Location 'ligne Lieu de rendez-vous utilisée pour les adresses
    objMsg.subject = Item.subject 'objet du mail
    
    'objMsg.HTMLBody = Item.body  'corps du mail
    Set itemInspector = Item.GetInspector
    Set itemWordEditor = itemInspector.WordEditor
    itemWordEditor.Range.Copy
    
    objMsg.Display
    
    Set objMsgInspector = objMsg.GetInspector
    Set objMsgWordEditor = objMsgInspector.WordEditor
    objMsgWordEditor.Range(0, 0).Paste

    'objMsg.Send

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but would you please comment it a bit : is it another sub that I should add or is it supposed to replace the one I have ? 
In the latter case it seems rather different than the one I postet, could you explain why it is so ? And I feel there is no check on an appointment category, and I of course do not want each appointment to be sent this way.
I somehow understand the logic of the code I reproduced, I do not yet the one of yours